# asp.net mvc 5 bundle jquery not working

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-5

my app is ok with debug and locally call jquery 3.3.1 but after publish app everything is ok javascrips and css but my dropdown menu need to jquery not working . i want to use this bundles in view page dont use in layout pleas helpe me ...
my budlens class include

```
    public static void Registerbundles(BundleCollection bundles)

     {
       bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

        //jquery
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
                                                       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js")
                                                       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")
                                                       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js")
                                                       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js")
                                                       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.map")
                                                       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1-vsdoc.js"));

       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

       // java script
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
                                                        .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
                                                        .Include("~/Scripts/jalaali.js")
                                                        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.Bootstrap-PersianDateTimePicker.js"));


        // bootsrtap CSS
        //bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/", "*.css", true));


       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                                                            "~/Content/bootstrap.theme.min.css" ,                           
                                                            "~/Content/site.css",
                                                            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                                                            "~/Content/bootstrap.theme.css",
                                                            "~/Content/jquery.Bootstrap-PersianDateTimePicker.css"
                                                                                         ));


        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

    }
```

and call in view ...

```
<script src="~/bundles/jQuery" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/bundles/scripts" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="~/bundles/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that bundling uses `src`/`href` pattern like that? Usually it uses `System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jQuery")` (for JS files) or `System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")` (for CSS files).

Comment: tank you for reply . i check this command but anything not changed ...

Comment: Use browser's dev tools (F12), check the console and network tab. If you got any errors include them as details. Is that the stylesheets and JS scripts are still not working, even you're using `Render()`?

Comment: even i using render still not working  i have 2 error in consol <br/> 1 https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED <br/> 2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) <br/> 3 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Usually I used `*` wildcard like this: `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-*")`. It will include all of jQuery scripts, and works fine for both local and production machines.

Answer (score 0):

The `-` character might cause the issue. Try renaming your files, for example, from `"~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"` to `"~/Scripts/jquery.3.3.1.js"`.  Apply this change to all your bundled resources.

Comment: thanx for reply . i chenged the charachter(-) to point (.) but still not working @remus

Comment: i used "~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" for locally is working perfectly but after publish and i use src="~/bundles/jQuery" not working . @Remus

Answer (score 0):

The view path might cause the issue.Try to rearrange your view path like these

```
<script src="~/bundles/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that Debugging JavaScript in your browser ,here put the break points and find your solution as well.
Debugging JavaScript in chrome(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbEx0s06VLs&t=4s).

Answer (score 0):

I created new bundles

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueSlim").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.slim.js"));
```

And I call it on the master page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueSlim")
```

Using System.Web.Optimization